# Scale, rotate, and translation operations from four points

Tags: linear-transformations

Given two pairs of points P1 and P2 as well as Q1 and Q2 in 2D-space. I am looking for a sequence of operations that will map P1 to Q1 and P2 to Q2:

- scale the coordinates by amount S with origin OS
- rotate the coordinates by angle ALPHA with origin OR
- translate the coordinates by TX and TY

How do I compute the transformation variables? I am looking for S, OS, OR, ALPHA, TX, TY.

If multiple solutions are possible, I am looking for the one that minimizes the translation (TX^2+TY^2).

Comment: What are origins OS and OR? Are they fixed? Or it is something we want to find too?

Comment: Well, surely you'll know how to scale coordinates, right? You just have to multiply the values by a scaling factor $\alpha>0$. So
$$
(x,y) \qquad \text{becomes} \qquad (\alpha\cdot  x, \alpha\cdot  y)
$$

Comment: @MattiP. Sure, I am looking rather for a way to derive the constants.

Comment: Okay, so what did you try so far? Have you, for example, derived the new coordinates after the first step, or second step?